# Error en código de contraseñas

Tags: java

Lo que necesito es que al dar una contraseña incorrecta el programa la solicite de nuevo 3 veces, una vez llegado a las 3 veces, mostrar un mensaje que dice "acceso denegado" y se reinicia el contador

El detalle es que aunque la contraseña sea incorrecta la da como correcta.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int login=0;
    int pass=0;
    int intentos=1;
    int maximo=3;
    Integer.parseInt(this.jTextField1.getText());
    Integer.parseInt(this.jPasswordField1.getText());
    while( ((login!=1809)||(pass!=1234)) && (intentos<maximo))
        {

            if(intentos==3)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "acceso denegado");
                intentos=intentos-maximo;
            }
            intentos++;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario y contraseña correctos");
}
```

Comment: En tu código no veo exactamente dónde comparas la contraseña ni con qué la comparas ¿? Se supone que debe haber una fuente de datos que verifique al usuario y si la contraseña que escribió es la correcta ¿no?

Comment: ¿Y eso como lo hago?

Comment: En esa función ni login, ni pass se modifican nunca, siempre valen 0, con lo que las comprobaciones en el while no sirven de nada. login siempre será distinto de 1809 y pass distinto de 1234. Imagino que la intención era asignarles lo que está retornando los parseInt del contenido de los campos de texto, pero no se lo asignas a nadie. Por otro lado, entiendo que el usuario teclea la password y pulsa el botón que hace ejecutar ese código, con lo que los intentos deberías comprobarlos cada vez que pulsa el botón, no comprobar todos los intentos en una sola pulsación.

Answer (score 0):

Primero te cambié el `while` por el `do while` para que entre siempre la primer vez. Después saqué `intentos<maximo` ya que cuando esa condición es falsa te saca del bucle, y no te debería sacar por que eso implica que el programa continúa su ejecución. O sea este tipo de algoritmos de chequear contraseña se suelen usar de forma que mientras el usuario ingrese datos incorrectos queda atrapado dentro del bucle y el programa no puede continuar, una especie de cepo. Otra cosa importante es que después de evaluar `login` y `pass` debes volver a asignar los campos `jTextField1` y `jPasswordField1`. Fijate que te cambié varias cositas:

```
    int login;
    int pass;
    int intentos=0;
    int maximo=3;
    do
        {
            if(intentos==3)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "acceso denegado");
                intentos=0;
            }
            login=Integer.parseInt(this.jTextField1.getText());
            pass=Integer.parseInt(this.jPasswordField1.getText());
            if(login == 1809 && pass == 1234)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario y contraseña correctos");
            intentos++;
        }

        while(login!= 1809 || pass!= 1234);
```